# OCaml "reading" a matrix (list of lists)

Tags: eclipse, ocaml

I have this problem in which i want to change the value of the element in col ln of a matrix i already have a function for that but i think i can make a better one, the only thing is i can´t think of another way of getting an element from the matrix and putting it back
 i can get it using

List.nth c (List.nth lb m)

but im having trouble putting it back

what i have for now is (fun left and right not done)

```
matrixleft m @(( List.nth c (List.nth lb m) ) + 1 )::matrixright m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks OK to me on a complexity basis, though it's going to traverse the input matrix twice--once to get the old value and once to install the new one. You can get the answer by traversing just once if you don't mind some more fiddly coding.

If you aren't following some externally imposed requirement, you would be better off using a real matrix (an array of arrays). Then there's no traversing, so you get constant time updates.

Comment: i have a code that does just that, going to the lines then columns, and then updates and stops, problem is i don´t know if im allowed to, and that way seems more the way they want me to do it, do you mind putting here an example of the code that traverses once? to see if it´s similar to mine